# Using the php engine inside a c# application

Tags: c#, php, winforms

I would like to give my users the ability to configure some php script to interact with my applycation.

I would like to give the user a Memo. The user writes some code with a php syntax, then press execute. The php engine executes the code, so I can print a result.

For example I would like to write something like:

```
PHPassembly = Assembly.LoadFrom("php5ts.dll"); 
ExecutePHPScript(PHPassembly,StringContainingAScript);
ResultVar=GetPHPVar(PHPassembly,"ResultVar");
```

I don't have a web server. I don't have an internet connection. Only a local application for windows.

I have tryed to load the php5ts.dll, but the compiler says that I need an assembly manifest.

Someone knows how to interact with php?

Comment: Would executing something on the command line be an option? I don't think you can use PHP directly in managed code - at least I don't know of any project that tries to make that possible.

Comment: @Stefan Gehrig: Command line is not an option. For example I would like to be like Apache (I don't want to use Apache). When I was developing with Delphi I used this kind of technique.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need 2 files (from php-5.3.5-Win32-VC9-x86) php-win.exe and php5ts.dll
Than just place those 2 files in you executable directory and run:

```
string code = "echo 'test';";

System.Diagnostics.Process ProcessObj = new System.Diagnostics.Process();
ProcessObj.StartInfo.FileName = "php-win.exe";
ProcessObj.StartInfo.Arguments = String.Format("-r \"{0}\"", code);
ProcessObj.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
ProcessObj.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
ProcessObj.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
ProcessObj.Start();
ProcessObj.WaitForExit();
string Result = ProcessObj.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
MessageBox.Show(Result);
```

Comment: a pretty good solution, but not so convenient: I have to create a process each time. It's like using it via command line: not a real integration.

Comment: how do you image doing it else way? Just Create a process with all parameters outside executing code, and just change arguments every time you execute code

Comment: It doesn't matter if u run code with -r (code) or -F (file), u have to start php to retrieve result. "Same thing" does Apache but in background ;)

Comment: really? Does Apache run a separate php instance for each php request? I don't think so: I have never seen the process "php-win.exe".

Comment: When php is run as CGI apache creates process for each request, when run as module, there is one process executed with every request (almost same as i proposed). Same thing would be with running php without apache, but with nginx, you would have to create process with every request.

Answer (score 0):

You can try hosting the php runtime locally. There are preconfigured packages for that, with PHP + Apache, like [xampp](http://www.apachefriends.org/en/xampp.html) and [WampServer](http://www.wampserver.com/en/). This way, you can call it via HTTP requests to `localhost` (such an approach is discussed [here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/netfxnetcom/thread/c18dae07-5f7e-4338-9202-2e7690a0cc3a/)).

Comment: No web server. No other application running. Only dll link or similar.

Comment: Well, then there's Phalanger (http://www.php-compiler.net/), which allows one to compile PHP into .NET, but I don't know if it could be used to solve your problem. EDIT: You could also try installing just PHP, without a webserver, and invoking the scripts via CLI.

Comment: Phalanger is a php compiler. I want to integrate php engine in my applications.

Comment: I know. The suggestion was to integrate by means of turning the user's php script into a .net assembly, and calling it through "normal" means...

Answer (score 0):

With a bit of configuration,you could execute your code against php running on the command line.

See [php.net for more info](http://php.net/manual/en/features.commandline.php)

Comment: a pretty good solution, but not so convenient: I have to create a shell process each time. Not a real integration.

Answer (score -1):

in search of something similar myself I found this question.

maybe port and include code from http://ph7.symisc.net/index.html if you don't need too fancy php stuff?

Comment: this hardly answers the question, so it should not be posted as an answer.